# qml FolderListModel

Tags: design-patterns, model, delegates, qt4, qml

I am trying to use FolderListModel, according to this [example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-folderlistmodel.html#)

like this:

```
 ListView
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    FolderListModel
    {
        id: foldermodel
        folder: "C:/Qt/Projects/"
        showDirs: true
        showDotAndDotDot: true
        nameFilters: ["*"]
        sortField :  "Name"
    }
    Component {
        id: filedelegate
        Text { text: fileName }
    }
    model: foldermodel
    delegate: filedelegate
}
```

i want to show all the files/directories under the base directory, in a recursive way.
does any one have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you have an invalid URL in the *folder* property. [Documentation for FolderListModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-folderlistmodel.html#folder-prop) element describes 'folder' property as:

> The folder property holds a URL for the folder that the model is currently providing. The value is a URL expressed as a string, and must be a file: or qrc: URL, or a relative URL. By default, the value is an invalid URL.

This means that the folder property must be in format `folder: "file:///[Directory path]"`. For instance, try changing your folder property in this case to: `folder: "file:///C:/Qt/Projects/"` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I think this cant be done without crawling the fs , this would requiere to create a list model and copy the tree inside ...

btw beware of cycles , filter . and .. out

-- 
http://rzr.online.fr/q/qml