# Recursevly go trough delegated maps in FolderListModel (QML)

Tags: qt, qml, subdirectory

I'm creating a music player for Ubuntu Touch in QML and I have some things I would appreciate some help with since I'm new to QML.

The app are able to play tracks listed in the selected directory, but the directory also shows folders, and I want all the files from all the subdirs to be listed, instead of only the tracks in the root dir.

But I don't really know how to do this. FolderListModel har a isFolder method that perhaps could be used, but I don't know how. Or use some kind of function to go trough the selected dirctory.

I came by this thread [qml FolderListModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563243/qml-folderlistmodel) but it didn't give me anything.

This is the code that currently lists my tracks:

```
            Column {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                anchors.fill: parent
                ListView {
                    id: musicFolder
                    FolderListModel {
                        id: folderModel
                        folder: musicDir
                        nameFilters: ["*.ogg","*.mp3","*.oga","*.wav"]
                    }
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    model: folderModel
                    delegate: ListItem.Subtitled {
                        text: fileName
                        subText: "Artist: "
                        onClicked: {
                            console.debug('Debug: User pressed '+musicDir+fileName)
                            playMusic.source = musicDir+fileName
                            playMusic.play()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a proxy model which flattens the nested items recursively. One example of such a proxy model is the [KDescendantsProxyModel](http://code.woboq.org/kde/kdelibs/kdeui/itemviews/kdescendantsproxymodel.h.html) (I'm also [using it](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=trojita.git&a=blob&h=2817262ab0dc29fa9fc8c2937c21bc7f1eea42b3&hb=085c3355a53fc1e3be0a2db94afca43ce118566c&f=src%2FImap%2FModel%2Fkdeui-itemviews%2Fkdescendantsproxymodel.cpp)).

Alternatively, you could build a list of files matching a particular pattern via recursively walking the filesystem (or letting some existing class do this for you) and feeding the result to some other, simpler model. That would have a disadvantage of not being able to display updates easily.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to create an array somehow, and then print that.